# How do I Post array data into database in Laravel 8

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am trying to post array data to the database but I keep getting this error `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given, called in /home/**/****/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php on line 886`

```
$nor = array(
            'no_of_rounds' => $request->no_of_rounds,
       );
 $data= New Item();
$data->no_of_rounds = $nor;
$data->save();
```

**Blade**

```
 <select class="selectpicker" name="no_of_rounds[]" multiple data-live-search="true" width="100%" id="no_of_rounds">
  <option value="90">Round 1</option>
  <option value="100">Round 2</option>
  <option value="110">Round 3</option>
   <option value="120">Round 4</option>
   <option value="130">Round 5</option>
   </select>
```

And when I dump I get this error
[image]

Comment: You can encode the array as a `JSON` object and save to a `JSON` column with `json_encode($nor)`

Comment: @Tithira, how can I save to JSON?

Comment: replace this `$data->no_of_rounds = $nor;` with `$data->no_of_rounds = json_encode($nor);` .  your error is mostly due to trying to push the array into a a column accepting a string, you may want to change your column type in your migration to `$table->json('data');` to get rid of it

Comment: @Tithira and what about retrieving the stored array to the blade since it is not decoded?

Comment: Use the PHP function `serialize()` to convert arrays to strings. These strings can easily be stored in MySQL database. Using `unserialize()` something like : `serialize($nor)`

Comment: You have to decode json with `json_decode($nor)` or `json_decode($nor, true)` in your blade file, it would be a better option to go with casting as answered below @Александр Черножуков, you wouldn't have to do this manually. check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is thrown because you are trying to insert an `array` straight into the database. It first has to be serialized. You could store it as `JSON`. See example below.

```
$nor = array(
    'no_of_rounds' => $request->no_of_rounds,
);

$item = Item::create([
    'no_of_rounds' => json_encode($nor),
]);
```

The casting process can be automated by Laravel as proposed in another [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68312608/3283698) by @Александр Черножуков.

Comment: and what about retrieving the stored array to blade since it is not decoded?

Comment: You can simply use `json_decode($item->nor)` for that. The answer of @Александр Черножуков gives you a solution so you do not have to that manually! If you set the `casts` attribute on your Item model, it will cast the automatically from `array` to `JSON` and vice versa.

Comment: I am getting this error when retrieving array, `Call to undefined function jsond_encode() `

Comment: You should use decode when retrieving the array. The correct function name is: `json_decode()`, not `jsond_encode()` you have made a typo in your function. So to encode use: `json_encode()`. To decode, use: `json_decode()`.

Comment: Thanks, one more last question, how do I format the output `"{\"no_of_rounds\":\"Round 1\"}""`. . This is how I have done it `{!! json_encode($order->no_of_rounds) !!}`

Comment: To display, you should `json_decode()` function. The `json_encode()` function to convert an `array` to JSON, The `json_decode()` function is used to decode the `JSON` back to `array`. Please see the answer of @Александр Черножуков because this can also be handled by Laravel!

Comment: When I use json_decode() function I get this error `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`.  This is how I have implemented `{!! json_decode($order->no_of_rounds) !!}` and this is how it is in database `"{\"no_of_rounds\":\"Round 1\"}"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234683/discussion-between-eric-landheer-and-dominic).

Comment: Bad answet. It is inconvenient and not practical to write like this every time. It is more convenient to use Casting

Comment: @Александр Черножуков I have referred to your answer as well in the comments. I will edit my post so it contains a reference to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

This best resolve
This will automatically convert to json when saving and back when reading into an array or collection, depending on your needs.
Insert this code in your Model

```
protected $casts = [
        'no_of_rounds' => 'collection',//For collection
        'no_of_rounds' => 'array'//For array
    ];
```